# Most efficient way to join/lookup/map column values in Dask?

Tags: python, dask

Given a Dask DataFrame, I'm trying to find the most efficient way to apply a static value lookup.

Example problem: My data has a column `"user_id"` with four possible values `[4823, 1292, 9634, 7431]`. I want to map these values to `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and store the result as a new column `"user_id_mapped"`.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this in Dask? One possibility is to left join of the main `df` to a `lookup_df`, but a join is a fairly complex operation. Even in plain Pandas an index based solution is typically much faster than a join/merge, e.g.:

```
N = 100000
user_ids = [4823, 1292, 9634, 7431]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "user_id": np.random.choice(user_ids, size=N),
    "dummy": np.random.uniform(size=N),
})

id_lookup_series = pd.Series(data=[0, 1, 2, 3], index=user_ids)

df["user_id_mapped"] = id_lookup_series[df["user_id"]].reset_index(drop=True)
```

I wasn't able to transfer this approach to Dask, because the static `id_lookup_series` is a plain Pandas series, whereas the index `df["user_id"]` is a Dask series. Is it possible to perform this kind of fast join in Dask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Pandas Solution

You can use merge if you convert your Pandas series to a DataFrame

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: N = 100000

In [4]: user_ids = [4823, 1292, 9634, 7431]

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     "user_id": np.random.choice(user_ids, size=N),
   ...:     "dummy": np.random.uniform(size=N),
   ...: })
   ...: 
   ...: id_lookup_series = pd.Series(data=[0, 1, 2, 3], index=user_ids)
   ...: 

In [6]: result = df.merge(id_lookup_series.to_frame(), left_on='user_id', right_
   ...: index=True)

In [7]: result.head()
Out[7]: 
       dummy  user_id  0
0   0.416698     1292  1
1   0.053371     1292  1
6   0.407371     1292  1
14  0.772367     1292  1
18  0.958009     1292  1
```

#### Dask Dataframe Solution

Everything above works fine with Dask.dataframe as well.  I wasn't sure if you knew the user ID's ahead of time or not, so I added in a step to compute them.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd
N 
In [3]: N = 100000

In [4]: user_ids = [4823, 1292, 9634, 7431]

In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     "user_id": np.random.choice(user_ids, size=N),
   ...:     "dummy": np.random.uniform(size=N),
   ...: })

In [6]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [7]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)

In [8]: user_ids = ddf.user_id.drop_duplicates().compute()

In [9]: id_lookup_series = pd.Series(list(range(len(user_ids))), index=user_ids.values)

In [10]: result = ddf.merge(id_lookup_series.to_frame(), left_on='user_id', right_index=True)

In [11]: result.head()
Out[11]: 
       dummy  user_id  0
0   0.364693     4823  0
5   0.934778     4823  0
14  0.970289     4823  0
15  0.561710     4823  0
21  0.838962     4823  0
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no need to worry about doing a full `df.merge`? I should have emphasized that this is what I was trying to avoid. Last time I benchmarked `df.merge` over the index based lookup it was slower by a factor of ~4 (just in pure Pandas), and I was worried it could be worse in a distributed setting. Still good to know that there is no way around `df.merge` here.

Comment: A dask.dataframe + pandas merge should have roughly the same performance as a pandas + pandas merge.  You could also try doing a `map_partitions` call if you have something faster.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why the provided code is so complicated. From what I read in your example problem description, you need to replace one set of values with another, so you do with [`Series.replace(to_replace={})`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) method in combination with `Dask.DataFrame.map_partitions()`:

```
def replacer(df, to_replace):
    df['user_id_mapped'] = df['user_id'].replace(to_replace=to_replace)
    return df

new_dask_df = dask_df.map_partitions(
    replacer,
    to_replace={4823: 0, 1292: 1, 9634: 2, 7431: 3}
)
```

P.S. You might want to learn about `meta` parameter to `map_partitions`, and consider to organize the code into a class to make it nicer and to avoid closures, but that is another topic.

Comment: Yes, in the end I also went for a `map_partitions` approach. Note that there is no need for `Series.replace`. With `map_partitions` I can simply use the indexing based technique presented in the question, which is slightly faster than `Series.replace` (at least in my benchmark).